# How to remove escaped character when parsing xml to json with copy data activity in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: json, xml, azure-data-factory

I have an ADF pipeline exporting from xml dataset (ADLS) to json dataset (ADLS) with a copy Data activity. Due to the complex xml structure, I need to parse the nested xml to nested json then use T-SQL to parse the nested json into Synapse table.

However, the output nested has double backslash (It seems like escape characters) at nodes which have comma in it. You can check a sample of xml input and json output below:

xml input

```
<Address2>test, test</Address2>
```

json output

```
"Address2":"test\\, test"
```

How can I remove the double backslash in the output json with copy data activity in Azure Data Factory ?

Comment: Please do not remove necessary data from your post. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the version with all necessary information of the post is the one which is distributed.

Comment: @Adriaan, I modified the data so that the sensitive information will not be exposed in the future without affecting the question solution

Comment: You should've thought about that before publicly releasing it under the CC BY-SA license. Thanks for the new edit though, that leaves the code intact. Note that your "sensitive information" is still visible in [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70328991/revisions) of this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such provision in `CopyData` Activity.

However, I just tried with just the lines you provided as sample source and sink with CopyData Activity and it just copies as is. I don't see any `\\`. Perhaps you could share the exact pipeline you have, with details of the nested XML, JSON and T-SQL that you are using.

**Repro:** (with all default settings and properties)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your answer hinted me to the correct approach to solve this. It was the csv dataset. The xml was pushed to the synapse table and export to csv dataset before the copy activity to json dataset. I fixed the escape character issue at the csv dataset. Thank you, your answer indeed pointed me to the solution.